# Simulated Annealing with integer parameters in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using Simulated Annealing in the MATLAB's Global Optimization Toolbox  to optimize a complex function. My function has only 3 parameters (x(1),x(2),x(3)) and 2 of them are integers (x(2) and x(3)). Right now I am running optimization by rounding x(2) and x(3) in the function itself and it takes a while for the algorithm to converge.

Is there a way to define x(2) and x(3) as integers and  have Simulated Annealing search only integer values?

Thanks!